# Insert record into mysql table using python : ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Tags: python

I am trying to insert data into mysql table using python:

```
add_user = ("INSERT INTO users_new "
                "(first_name, last_name, hire_date, gender, birth_date) "
                "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")


data_user = ('Ali', 'Ahmed', tomorrow, 'M', date(1977, 6, 14))

cursor.execute(add_user, data_user)
```

but I have the following error:

cursor.execute(add_user, data_user)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 555, in execute
    stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 86, in **call**
    "Not enough parameters for the SQL statement")
ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Comment: What is `add_employee`? Or `data_employee`, you've not shown either.

Comment: Guess on the common issue: `cursor.execute(add_employee, (data_employee,))`

Comment: Please provide a complete example without any additional errors other than the one you are asking about.

Comment: sorry , the following is the right code, add_user = ("INSERT INTO users_new "
                "(first_name, last_name, hire_date, gender, birth_date) "
                "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")


data_user = ('Ali', 'Ahmed', tomorrow, 'M', date(1977, 6, 14))

cursor.execute(add_user, data_user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know exact reason for that error without seeing code for `add_employee` and `data_employee`. But in your `add_user` and `add_group` it looks like you forgot to add the actual strings to format `%s` and `%()s`?

EDIT after clarification:

The problem is that you provide 8 when you really need 5 `%s`. Date is just one argument.

```
add_user = ("INSERT INTO users_new "
                "(first_name, last_name, hire_date, gender, birth_date) "
                "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")


data_user = ('Ali', 'Ahmed', tomorrow, 'M', date(1977, 6, 14))

cursor.execute(add_user, data_user)
```

Comment: sorry , this is the right code,add_user = ("INSERT INTO users_new "
                "(first_name, last_name, hire_date, gender, birth_date) "
                "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")


data_user = ('Ali', 'Ahmed', tomorrow, 'M', date(1977, 6, 14))

cursor.execute(add_user, data_user)